# Initialising array from a variable (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, initialization

Im currently doing a programming project, and I've come across a problem while compiling... I have this code made in C++:

```
scanf("%d %d", &number, &shares);
vector<int> graph[number];
```

I read the variable number, and use it to initialise the size of the array. But this produces a initialising problem,

> variable length array of non-POD element type `vector<int>`

Anyone knows what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to define an array of vectors, but arrays cannot have runtime determined sizes. Presumably, you want to declare a vector of a certain type, which you can do like this:

```
vector<int> graph(number); // vector of size = number
```

**Edit**: After your comments, it seems that what you're after is a vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<int>> graph(number);
```

Comment: Actually, I mean to do an Array of <Int>Vectors, to store the value of outgoing connections from a specific node, to use on Tarjan's Algorith for SCC's... But many thanks for your help!

Comment: @FranciscoTSilva OK, maybe you need a vector of vectors. See edit.

Comment: Thank you. You know of any guides where I can see examples of how to manipulate the structure defined like this?

Answer (score 2):

Check this related posts, as they have this same problem as yours:

- [c++: Error: variable length array of non-POD element type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881763/c-error-variable-length-array-of-non-pod-element-type)
- [Variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550712/variable-length-array-of-non-pod-element-type-string-aka-basic-stringchar)

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to create an array of vectors, which is not a good thing if you don't do this through dynamic allocation. If you want an array of vectors, do this:

```
vector<int> * graph = new vector<int>[number];
...
delete[] graph;
```

If you want to have a vector of size number, then do this:

```
vector<int> graph(number);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the first one you inputed! I have to do an implementation of Tarjan's algorithm, and to store the graph, I mean to use a number of nodes read from input, and then store in a vector in each position all of the outgoing connections of each node. I only meant to use the multidimensional array this way because I could initialise the array in the specific number of nodes that I read from input! Still, I will try this right away! Thank you!

Comment: Instead of this, do vector<vector<int>> graph(number);